# Login into website-

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to get my password but not user name into username box while performing below written code. Please let me know to get the username on its place and login into the website. Thanks in advance.

```
 Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
 Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
 Sub mylogin()

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
 Dim MyURL As String
 On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 MyURL = "confidential"
 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
 HTMLDoc.all.username.Value = "xxxx"
 HTMLDoc.all.password.Value = "xxx"
 For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("class")
 If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next
 Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable without the HTML code forming the logon `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it works like this.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Make sure you set references to...

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Internet Controls
```