# Logging in issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a vba to login to a website.

I am getting compilation error in below statement.

getting error in the username and pwd adding part

```
Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub daily()
'
' daily Macro
'

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

    '  website
    MYURL = ""
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document

    ' user login and password
    ' error here
    HTMLDoc.all.user-login.Value = ***
    HTMLDoc.all.user-password.Value = ***

    For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagName("input")
    'click submit to login
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next

 'gives debug error***   If MyHTML_Element.Type = "Reports" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next


Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: iam getting error in HTMLDoc.all.user-login.Value = ***
    HTMLDoc.all.user-password.Value = *** here. expected ( this is the error messege which iam getting

Comment: Did you replace the strings with `***` in this example or is that the actual code you are trying to use?

Comment: yes. i have replaced the usernam eand pwd with the actual value. but still no luck

Comment: Are you looking for the cause of the compile error  or for the runtime error? You cannot have both - as long as you have a compile error the code will not run at all (and therefore you can't get a runtime error)

Comment: You have an extra `Next` statement.

Comment: I'm assuming you added the required references for those objects. http://automatetheweb.net/how-to-add-vba-references-internet-controls-html-object-library/

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add these references:

> Microsoft HTML Object Library

> Microsoft Internet Controls

---

Your If statements need to use multiple line syntax to do more than one thing in the If.

---

And notice how VBA adds a space to this?

```
HTMLDoc.all.user -login.Value
```

That's because objects cannot have a `-` in the name, so it seems you have the wrong property.

---

I have tried to guess at what your other problems were and changed it to this to at least get you going in the right direction, but you still need to change those to the correct property names.

```
Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub daily()
'
' daily Macro
'

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

    '  website
    MYURL = ""
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document

    ' user login and password
    HTMLDoc.all.user -login.Value = "athi"
    HTMLDoc.all.user -Password.Value = "pw123"

    ' changed this part
    For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagName("input")
        If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then
            MyHTML_Element.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        If MyHTML_Element.Type = "Reports" Then MyHTML_Element.Click
    Next

Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If


End Sub
```

[Login into website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265475/login-into-website)